# Why is Google Drive invisible in command prompt mode?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, google-drive

I've been using Google Drive for a while with ups and downs. One major down that I recently discovered is that it doesn't appear in command prompt mode, although it appears fine in Windows Explorer.  As a result, some Windows applications that access folders based on their visibility from command prompt can't detect Google Drive. Google Drive's attribute is definitely not hidden either.

So, why is Google Drive invisible from command prompt, and is there any way to make Google Drive visible?

Comment: I'm running Google Drive under Windows 7, and the Google Drive folder is visible to me from the command prompt.

Comment: mmm. I'm on Windows 7 too. How come it doesn't show up in mine..

Comment: I don't see the google drive in Vista or XP either.. Are you sure it's visible? You can certainly move into the folder by "CD Google Drive", but the directory "Google Drive" is nowhere to be seen in its immediate parent directory. Thus my question.

Comment: `Google Drive` contains a space in the name. do you quote the name before giving it to `cd`? as in `cd "Google Drive"`?

Comment: If you read my question carefully, I said I have no problem moving into the Google Drive with the cd command. The question is why the directory is not visible in its parent directory when one can still move into it from the parent directory with the CD command.

Comment: I have the same problem (I think).  I created a scheduled task to copy a file into my google drive folder, thinking the google service will pick it up and backup it for me.  No luck - copy and xcopy both exit reporting a successful file copy, but the file never appears in the folder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dir /as` will display it for me, so it must have the **system** attribute.

Oddly enough, `dir /ad` (list directories) will also list it.

Running the `cmd.exe` as Administrator didn't help.